# unable to return the updated string from called function and free the memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have a simple program with two string which I supposed to concatenate in the called function and `return` to the calling function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void call_func(char *str1,char *str2)
{

  char *msg_concat;
  asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", str1, str2);
  printf("%s",msg_concat);
  str2 = msg_concat;

}



int main()
{
    char *str1="new" ;

    char *full_msg ="test";
    call_func(str1,full_msg);
    printf("value of full_msg=%s",full_msg);
    return 0;

}
```

I have used `asprintf()` for concatenation but the value is not returned in the main function. As I have used the pointer, is not it 
is expected to return the changed value??

Further while assigning the pointer , in my understanding reference is copied rather than the values. now here I need to free the
allocated memory msg_concat otherwise there will be memory leak . how am supposed to free memory if the function uses pointer and return the 
reference to the calling function??

`free(msg_concat)` is not working while  in the last line of called function
as-

```
void call_func(char *str1,char *str2)
{

  char *msg_concat;
  asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", str1, str2);
  printf("%s",msg_concat);
  str2 = msg_concat;
   free(msg_concat);

}
```

actually in my recent project, I have the scenerio that the calling function has

```
GSList *parsed_msg = LineParser(dev_ip,encoded_msg, "\n", file_path, unique_id);
```

and the called function is

```
GSList *LineParser(char* dev_ip, char *msg_full, char *separator, char *file_path, int unique_id)
{
    GSList *parsed_msg = NULL;
    char connection_id[50];
    sprintf(connection_id,"%s|%d", dev_ip, unique_id);
    char *msg_concat;


    // inserting {file_path : last_not_complete_line} logic to TCP_CACHE
    //and removing the correspoing last_line
    g_mutex_lock (&mutex_hash_main);

    // char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup((GHashTable *) g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id), file_path));

    GHashTable *t_filepath_msg_dict = NULL;         //for {file_path : last_not_complete_line}
    if (TCP_CACHE != NULL)
    {
        t_filepath_msg_dict = (GHashTable *)(g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id));
        if (t_filepath_msg_dict != NULL)
        {
            char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path));

            if(last_line != NULL)   //if the hash has device ip, append the value to msg
            {
                zlog_debug(c,"concatenating: str1: %s and str2: %s\n", last_line, msg_full);
                asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", last_line, msg_full);


                //msg_concat = concat(last_line,msg_full);
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);

                msg_full = msg_concat;

            }   
        }

    }


    int msg_len = strlen(msg_full);
    char last_char = msg_full[msg_len - 1];
    zlog_debug(c, "len of message: %d", msg_len);
    zlog_debug(c, "last char is : %c", last_char);
    char *token=NULL;
    char *remaining_str=NULL;
    token = strtok_r(msg_full, "\n", &remaining_str);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(token[0]==' ')
        {
            token = trimwhitespace_parser (token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
            {
                //insert this token to GSList
                parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(remaining_str,"")==0)
        {
            if(strlen(token) > 10000)
            {
                zlog_warn(c, "Message too big(more than 10000 len). Stop looking for new line and process msg");
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
            }
            else
            {
                if(last_char=='\n')
                {
                    //new line is the last character. do nothing
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is new line");
                }
                else
                {
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is not new line");
                    //new line not received
                    if (t_filepath_msg_dict == NULL)        //insert new record
                    {
                        GHashTable *each_filepath_msg_dict = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, key_str_destroy_cb_parser, value_str_destroy_cb_parser);
                        zlog_debug(c,"Inserting file_path: %s to connection_id: %s", file_path, connection_id);

                        g_hash_table_insert(each_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                        g_hash_table_insert(TCP_CACHE, strdup(connection_id), each_filepath_msg_dict);
                    }
                    else        //update existing record
                    {
                        zlog_debug(c,"Connection_id :%s is already found; appending/replacing file_path :%s", connection_id, file_path);
                        g_hash_table_insert(t_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                    }
                    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
                    return parsed_msg;
                }
            }
        }
        //insert token to GSList
        parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
    }
    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
    return parsed_msg;
}
```

I have seen that i have problem with memory leak as i have to free msg_concat,as in the given answer it is said that the changed value doesnot return to calling function. where is the appropriate place to free the asprintf msg_concat pointer???

Answer (score 1):

As `C` uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing, in your code

```
str2 = msg_concat;
```

is pretty much useless, in regard to returning the value to `main()`. Instead, you may want to use `strcpy()` to copy the content to the memory area pointed by `str2`, which will reflect in `main()`.

Also, after you have copied the content, you can `free()` the `msg_concat` before the end of `call_func()`.

---

Now, **even this** won't solve your issue, as you're calling `call_func()` with a second argument as a *string literal*. This is illegal in two ways

- modification of string literal will cause UB.
- the destination string (as used in `strcpy()`) won't have enough memory to hold the final output.

Solution: A possible way to solve this can be

Change the type of `full_msg` to a fixed length array, which has enough length to hold the concatenated output, like

```
char full_msg[32] = "test";
```

then, with a call like

```
call_func(str1,full_msg);
```

and inside, with a `strcpy(str2, msg_concat);`, you can achieve your goal.

Additionally, you can use `free(msg_concat);` also.

Comment: here msg_concat has concatenated value and when i assign it to the pointer str2, doesnot it return value to main?? str2 is pass by reference as it is a pointer

Comment: @user3545251 `str2` itself is passed-by-value, i.e., you can change `*str2` but you cannot change `str2` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are passed by value, so the last assignment has no effect in the caller. There are two ways to do what you wish:

- Pass a pointer to pointer for `str2`, or
- Return a new string to the caller.

Returning the result has a slightly more explicit appearance to the callers of your function, but the pointer-to-pointer approach is valid as well.

An additional issue that you need to solve is freeing the pointer passed into your function. You cannot pass a string literal if you would like to free the value:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* call_func(char *str1,char *str2) {
    char *msg_concat = NULL;
    asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", str1, str2);
    printf("%s",msg_concat);
    free(str2);
    return msg_concat;
}

int main() {
    char *str1="new" ;
    char *full_msg =strdup("test"); // Put the string in dynamic memory
    full_msg = call_func(str1, full_msg);
    printf("value of full_msg=%s", full_msg);
    free(full_msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understood that the string are pass by value thus it doesnot return the changed value, however in my above edited code ,I have tried to free the asprintf memory after calculation token using strtok but it is giving memory error using valgrind, where is the appropriate place to free the asprintf memory in the above context???

Comment: @user3545251 Did you miss the `strdup` part?

Comment: now if you look at my edited code, now i don't want to return the concatnated string but return the list and  I need to free the asprintf allocated memory which is causing problem to me.

Comment: @user3545251 The newly inserted code has very little in common with your original question, though.